# Passing variable into array inside function

Tags: microcontroller, keil

I have a code like this :

```
void display_character (char j,k,l,m)  {

unsigned char display [4] = {j,k,l,m}
.
.
.
.
}

void main()
 {

   while(1)
    {
      display_character(1,2,3,4);
      display_character(5,6,7,8);

    }//end of while
 }
```

How can I pass 1,2,3,4 into j,k,l,m in the array ?
**because I got error with this code :
error C247: non-address/-constant initializer**

Thank you

it doesn't work

```
void display_character (char j,k,l,m)  {

//unsigned char display [4] = {1,2,3,4}; // we can modify value of this variable in run time
unsigned char display [4]; // we can modify value of this variable in run time
                display[0]=j;
                display[1]=k;
                display[2]=l;
                display[3]=m;

unsigned char x,y,a,z;
.
.
.
```

error :
*

```
**32_8_MAIN.C(98): error C141: syntax error near 'unsigned'
32_8_MAIN.C(98): error C202: 'x': undefined identifier
32_8_MAIN.C(101): error C202: 'z': undefined identifier
32_8_MAIN.C(103): error C202: 'x': undefined identifier
32_8_MAIN.C(105): error C202: 'y': undefined identifier
32_8_MAIN.C(107): error C202: 'a': undefined identifier
32_8_MAIN.C(108): error C202: 'a': undefined identifier
32_8_MAIN.C(111): error C202: 'a': undefined identifier
32_8_MAIN.C(112): error C202: 'a': undefined identifier
32_8_MAIN.C(118): error C202: 'z': undefined identifier
32_8_MAIN.C(120): error C202: 'x': undefined identifier
32_8_MAIN.C(122): error C202: 'y': undefined identifier
32_8_MAIN.C(124): error C202: 'a': undefined identifier
32_8_MAIN.C(125): error C202: 'a': undefined identifier
32_8_MAIN.C(128): error C202: 'a': undefined identifier
32_8_MAIN.C(129): error C202: 'a': undefined identifier**
```

*

Comment: Looks like a software question, not electronics

Comment: it's electronics, this software is for MCS51 in Keil

Comment: It is a pure C question having nothing to do with electronics.  You could have the same question on any machine.

Comment: @RickAnt To clarify what these guys are saying, we do accept firmware question, but only when they some how relate to the specifics of the hardware they are on. Like if you are interfacing with a hardware PWM or something along those lines. Questions that don't have any hardware interaction should be on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably cannot initialize the variable with other variables, so 
unsigned char display [4] = {1,2,3,3} would be OK, but the way you wrote it isn't.

In that case just do like this:

```
unsigned char display [4];
display[0]=j;
display[1]=k;
display[2]=l;
display[3]=m;
```

it's not working

error :

```
32_8_MAIN.C(99): error C141: syntax error near 'unsigned'
32_8_MAIN.C(99): error C202: 'x': undefined identifier
32_8_MAIN.C(102): error C202: 'z': undefined identifier
32_8_MAIN.C(104): error C202: 'x': undefined identifier
32_8_MAIN.C(106): error C202: 'y': undefined identifier
32_8_MAIN.C(108): error C202: 'a': undefined identifier
32_8_MAIN.C(109): error C202: 'a': undefined identifier
32_8_MAIN.C(112): error C202: 'a': undefined identifier
32_8_MAIN.C(113): error C202: 'a': undefined identifier
32_8_MAIN.C(119): error C202: 'z': undefined identifier
32_8_MAIN.C(121): error C202: 'x': undefined identifier
32_8_MAIN.C(123): error C202: 'y': undefined identifier
32_8_MAIN.C(125): error C202: 'a': undefined identifier
32_8_MAIN.C(126): error C202: 'a': undefined identifier
32_8_MAIN.C(129): error C202: 'a': undefined identifier
32_8_MAIN.C(130): error C202: 'a': undefined identifier
Target not created
```

Comment: but give me another error, can you see my edit ? thanks

Comment: You've added a declaration of more variables (x.y etc) after some code, in C you have to do all the declarations at the start of a code block and before you start the code statements.

Answer (score 0):

it works :

```
void display_character (char j,k,l,m)  {
unsigned char x,y,a,z;

unsigned char display [4]; // we can modify value of this variable in run time

                    display[0]=j;
                    display[1]=k;
                    display[2]=l;
                    display[3]=m; 

.
.
.
.
}

display_character(1,2,3,4)
```

Comment: why did you include the "unsigned char x,y,a,z"? Well, I guess it was used somewhere in your code. Also display[4] should be display[3]. All the best. :)

Answer (score -1):

THIS SHOULD WORK................

void display_chacracter(j,k,l,m);  //declaration

void main()

{

while(1)

{

```
display_character(1,2,3,4);
display_character(5,6,7,8);
while(1);       //just to put a stop :)
}//end of while
```

}

void display_chacracter(j,k,l,m)

{

unsigned char j,k,l,m;

```
unsigned char display[3];

display[0]=j;
display[1]=k;
display[2]=l;
display[3]=m;
```

}

Comment: Downvoted because this is wrong, the number in brackets at the array declaration is number of elements, not max element index. From K&R: "The declaration
int ndigit[10];
declares ndigit to be an array of 10 integers. Array subscripts always start at zero in C, so
the elements are ndigit[0], ndigit[1], ..., ndigit[9]."